# Run Two Apps in My Operating system

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, nasm

I want to run app and kernel in my os at same time.

But when kernel jump loaded app kernel do their back operations (ex:Look CD-DVD Rom)

Example:

```
    bits 16 
    org 32768;<--------

;start of kernel

    start:
...

;Process

    Load:
    ....

    jmp 65535;I want to Kernel Do This operations in the back

    ....
```

;-----------------------App----------------------;

```
    bits 16 ;16 bit
    org 65535;<-----------
    start:
...some process...
jmp 32768 ;Cont. the kernel
```

Please Help
www.afcos.comuf.com

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is *multitasking*. In this case, you'll need to implement some sort of timer to trigger the context switch as well as implement context switching itself. [This](http://wiki.osdev.org/Multitasking_Systems) might provide some good information.

Comment: multitasking is not stop applications?

Comment: and i have a problem. Can i ask to you?

Comment: Multitasking will stop one application so another can run.

Comment: but i want to similar to Windows run the applications without stopping?

Comment: The trick is to switch applications fast enough so you get the *illusion* of multitasking.

Comment: You can email me at `quantumdude836 (at) gmail (dot) com`